# java playing sounds in order

Tags: java, audio

Hi I have following java programme that play some sounds.I want to play sounds in order for example after ending of sound1 i want to play sound2 and then sound3 the following is my java code and function of playing sound .

```
    private void playsound(String file)
{
     try {
     crit = AudioSystem.getClip();
    AudioInputStream inputStream1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getResource(file));
    crit.open(inputStream1);
    //if(!crit.isOpen())
    {

    crit.start();
    }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

and calling it as following

```
     playsound("/sounds/filesound1.au");
     playsound("/sounds/filesound2.au");
     playsound("/sounds/filesound3.au");
```

the programme is plying sound in parallel which I don't want.I want to play in order 
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the following code from somewhere that I can't remember right now but it plays the music consequently:

```
public static void play(ArrayList<String> files){
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    for (String filePath : files) {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        try {
            AudioInputStream is = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            AudioFormat format = is.getFormat();
            SourceDataLine line = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(format);
            line.open(format);
            line.start();
            while (is.available() > 0) {
                int len = is.read(buffer);
                line.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            line.drain();
            line.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The reason this plays the files consequently and not all at the same time is because `write` blocks until the requested amount of data has been written. This applies even if the requested amount of data to write is greater than the data line's buffer size.

Make sure to include `drain()` from the code above. `drain()` waits for the buffer to empty before it `close()`s.